# problem using twitter in application android

Tags: android, twitter

I used this link http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-twitter-with-oauth-on-andorid.html to use Twitter in my application Android.
But nothing appears in interface. Should I create the interface of authentification twitter or it generated directement by code. Can any one explain me why I didn't have any displayed

Answer (score 1):

Try this link also :
https://gist.github.com/97ed32efcada70516cc9

You will need:

- signpost-commonshttp4.....java
- signpost-core.....java

Search for these jar files on net...........

Hope it helps